# Javascript: Create regex dynamically

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this password regex:

```
var PasswordRegex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"]{8,}$/;
```

i now want the min length to be set from the admin CMS

so i have this

```
function CheckPassword(minLengh, Password) {
DynamicPasswordRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"]{" + minLengh + ",}$");

return DynamicPasswordRegex.test(Password);
}
```

for some reason, passwords that are ok, returned false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing a string literal, so your backslashes are being parsed as string literal escape sequences.

You need to escape every backslash as `\\` so that the regex sees a single backslash.

Comment: Just figured that out and come to answer